# Why doesn't my Youtu.be URL work for video embedding?

Tags: html, youtube

I want to embed a YouTube video link in my web page with something like `url://youtu.be`. It's not appearing when I embed that in my web page. The below code, however, is working well (`url://youtube` without the dot).

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4pXUcxWLA7g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Why does using a "youtu.be" link not embed properly?

Comment: More info, more data and maybe check Youtubes documentation itself...

Comment: Give us code of you webpage

Comment: `code`<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4pXUcxWLA7g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`code`

Comment: i m using <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtu.be/4pXUcxWLA7g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: remove dot from yuotu.be. Should be youtube

Answer (score 6):

Because youtu.be is a URL shortening service. So when you go to a you.be URL, all it does is Redirect you to the full URL for a video.

**Edit**, actually that's not the complete end of the story. What happens when you do that is yes, it redirects you, but then the browser gives an error:

> "Refused to display (video url) in a frame because it set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."

So, this *could* work with redirection, but it doesn't because youtube sends down this response

> header: x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN

And so the browser refuses to display it because it's not the same origin (that is, it's not being served from the same domain). *Why* does youtube do this? That I don't know. But, basically, it appears you MUST you the youtube.com/embed style URL for iframe. If you have URLs in the youtu.be format (maybe in your database or something), then you will need to hit the youtu.be link and then see where it wants to redirect you to, and then use THAT link for your iframe.

Comment: thanks, i got this link from JSON, i have no control to change it into JSON file how can i use or manipulate this link for embed in web page . please share some suggestions.

Comment: Well, it's *probably* the case that all you need to do is

`var url = "youtu.be/4pXUcxWLA7g";
url = url.replace("youtu.be","youtube.com/embed")`

Comment: @aquinas your comment is simply the correct answer , please add it as an answer for future visitors, thank you.

Comment: @aquinas dude add this to your answer, This is a lot helpful

Answer (score 0):

In case you use JavaScript simply use string replace function to replace the *youtu.be* part to *youtube.com/embed* like in comments

```
let youtubelink = 'youtu.be/video_link_path';
youtubelink = youtubelink.replace('youtu.be', 'youtube.com/embed');
```

in case of php the script is slightly different you can run the above statement in PHP like

```
$youtubelink = 'youtu.be/video_link_path';
$youtubelink = str_replace("youtu.be","youtube.com/embed", $youtubelink);
```